# Using Datagridview, taking an existing column and making them hyperlinks

Tags: c#, datagridview, hyperlink

The fifth column in my `DataGridView` is pulling information from `resumelink` in our SQL server. The name of the file is the only thing in the resumelink record, eg. **DOC100.pdf** or **Name12.pdf**. I need those to link to a mapped drive on the computer so, if the name of the file is **DOC100.pdf**, it needs to be `//nt/resume/DOC100.pdf`. I need to store the `//nt/resume` part and then just add what's in the resumelink field. I have a field called `dataGridView1_CellContentClick` but it's currently empty. I'm not concerned as to how the pdf's open, whether it's in IE or Adobe.

Here's a picture of how the program looks.

[image]

```
namespace ResumeTest
{
public partial class Resume : Form
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

    public Resume()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'iHBAPPSDataSet.HRresume' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
       this.hRresumeTableAdapter.Fill(this.iHBAPPSDataSet.HRresume);
       this.dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
       this.dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       bindingSource1.Filter = "name LIKE '%" + name.Text + "%' AND skillset LIKE '%" + skillset.Text + "%'";
    }

    public void ClearTextBoxes(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                if (!(c.Parent is NumericUpDown))
                {
                    ((TextBox)c).Clear();
                }
            }
            else if (c is NumericUpDown)
            {
                ((NumericUpDown)c).Value = 0;
            }
            else if (c is ComboBox)
            {
                ((ComboBox)c).SelectedIndex = 0;
            }

            if (c.HasChildren)
            {
                ClearTextBoxes(c);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearTextBoxes(this);
        bindingSource1.Filter = "name LIKE '%" + name.Text + "%'";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add f2 = new Add();
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Delete f3 = new Delete();
        f3.Show();
    }

    private void refreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.hRresumeTableAdapter.Fill(this.iHBAPPSDataSet.HRresume);
    }

    private void quitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why not return `'//nt/resume/' + resumelink As resumelink` from sql server itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
      // set the part of filename You have to add to some constant
      // or save it in some external file and read here to be able to edit this value
      // without rebuilding of the project
      const string filePreName = @"//nt/resume/";

      // get the clicked filename value
      string filename = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

      // combine file pre name and file name
      string finalFilePath = filePreName + filename;

      // this function will start default program, which is configured in your system
      // to handle pdf files and will open selected pdf file in this program
      // to get access to this function you should reference to

      // using System.Diagnostics;

      // at the top of current class file
      Process.Start(finalFilePath);
}
```

Or put all in one line:

```
Process.Start(@"//nt/resume/" + dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value);
```

P.S. This will not change the display of file name in datagrid (which I think is even better than display long string like `//nt/resume/DOC100.pdf` in one cell) but will handle file opening correctly.